# How to replace the value in nested arrays in multiple mongodb docs at once

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, subquery

Here i wanted to replace the value of country to something else wherever it presents like "India".
I have multiple docs with same structure and would like update all at once. It should not affect other keys and just wanted to update the country.

Tried with Set operator and not getting it correctly.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "teams" : 
    [ 
        {
            "type" : "local",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "Country":"India"
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "national",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "Country":"India"
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "international",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "Country":"England"
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "national",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "Country":"India"
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "international",
            "isEnabled" : "true",
            "Country":"Newzealand"
            "names" : 
            [ 
                { "name": "kumar","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Goa","Age":"U25" },
                { "name": "kannan","Nationality":"indian","BirthPlace":"Kerala","Age":"U25"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   { $set: { "teams.$[element].Country": "Republic of India" } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ "element.Country": "India" }] }
);
```

Comment: Sorry was away due to sick.
This helps.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
 {
   $set: {
    "teams.$[].Country": "India"
   }
})
```